# How to Send AS3 data to CakePHP

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, cakephp

I'm wondering how to send data from AS3 to CakePHP. I know I can use URLVariables to send data to the URLRequest and ge that data in PHP using the superglobal $_POST. However, for some reason I can't access the variables in a CakePHP action.

In my action I get the data using the following:

```
    echo json_encode(array("response_type" => $responseType,"response" => $response, "data" => $_POST));
```

but this is what I get in return:

```
{"response_type":"Error","response":"Data was not sent!","data":[]}
```

**Note**: I have set responeType to "Error" and response to "Data was not.." manually.

In AS3 this is what I do:

```
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
    request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    request.data = params;

    loader = new URLLoader();

    executeRequest(loader, request);
```

And this is what I send as my object:

```
{facebookID:"25"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using [`URLVariables` (as in example)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html#data)

Comment: That was exactly my problem. I though the data property would just take an object, but I guess not.